# Finding tangents to a circle with a straightedge

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction, plane-geometry

There is a geometric construction that I heard years ago and I still haven't figured out why it works despite several attempts.
Playing with pen, paper and GeoGebra makes me confident that it does indeed work.
Could someone explain it to me?

**Task:**
Given a circle and a point outside it, construct the two tangents to the circle through the point, using only a straightedge.

**Solution:**
Draw any three different lines through the given point $P$ that intersect the circle twice.
Let $A_1,A_2,B_1,B_2,C_1,C_2$ be the six intersection points, with the same letter corresponding to the same line and the index 1 corresponding to the point closer to $P$.
Let $D$ be the point where the lines $A_1B_2$ and $A_2B_1$ intersect, and similarly $E$ for the lines $B_1C_2$ and $B_2C_1$.
Draw a line through $D$ and $E$.
This line meets the circle at two points, $F$ and $G$.
The tangents are $PF$ and $PG$.

Answer (score 6):

It is a consequence of Pascal's theorem in Projective geometry valid for any conic, the circle is a special case. When separation tends to zero, the secant points  $(OA_1, OA_2)$ where $(A_1, A_2) $ are extremities of chord on circle  which multiply to tangent point $F$ as

$ OA_1 OA_2= OB_1 OB_2=...= OD_1 OD_2= PF^2$ as constant product, a property of the circle.

The locus,chord  $ FG $, is a straight line. As a property of circle it is the *harmonic mean of segments* $ (OA_1, OA_2) $ as,for all chords e.g.,

$$  2/PF = 1/OA_1 + 1/OA_2. $$

**Conclusion:**

*Pascal line is the chord of harmonic means of a pencil/circle intersection*

[image: Pascal Line Circle]

Pascal Line valid on ellipse also, but I do not know if that is the harmonic locus. (posted Sept 2, 2016).

[image: Pascal Line Ellipse]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer completely. I was previously unaware of Pascal's theorem and it seems useful. You say that the Pascal line corresponding to the choice of the three lines is the line $FG$. But the Pascal line could change if we change the three lines, so I don't see how the limit argument works exactly. It seems that the Pascal line is indeed independent of the choice of the three lines, but this requires an argument. And I don't see how the harmonic mean is relevant here. Can you elaborate?

Comment: If $ A_1 $ is brought near to $ A_2$ by shifting up our straight edge  it tends to position $F$.as a double point of tangency.  Similarly with $C'$ s and $G$.      Since  harmonic mean leads to an invariant property chord line for all rays like $ PA_1A_2, ...,...$  the initial choice in relative positioning of $ A, B , C $ should not matter.

Comment: Added a hand made Paint sketch, poor accuracy, for sake of reference. The pole/polar discussion is also relevant here.,

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your construction is a *perspective image* (a central projection) of 'something' drawn on some plane $p$, with the point $P$ being on the horizon of the perspective, that is 'in infinity'. What is the 'original' drawing on the plane $p$ then?

Well, it is an ellipse, with three *parallel* lines $A,B,C$ crossing it.

Now, we can apply a shear transformation to the $p$ plane to transform the ellipse into a circle. A shear mapping preserves collinearity, parallelism and tangency, so the transformed image would be a circle with three parallel lines $A,B,C$ crossing it.

The respective chords of the circle are parallel, so they are bases of two trapezoids.
Due to the circle's symmetry, those trapezoids are isosceles and have a common axis of symmetry, *and* that axis goes through the circle's center point.
The diagonals of isosceles trapezoids cross on the axis of symmetry, so your $DE$ line is the same axis. It goes through the center of the circle and it is *perpendicular* to the $A,B,C$ lines
– so $FG$ is a diameter perpendicular to $A,B,C$, and its endpoints are tangency points for two lines paralel to $A,B,C$.

And those tangent lines meet $A,B,C$ in $P$ on the original construction due to properties of perspective mapping, so the construction is correct.

Comment: This sounds like a very interesting idea. Can you give more details about the transformation you apply to the original picture to move *P* to infinity? The idea is good, but I fail to reconstruct the exact transformation from your text.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that the points $E,F$ are on the polar $p$ of $P$ with respect to the circle, and the tangents from $P$ go through the points where $p$ intersects the circle.  Moreover, this construction works for all conics, not just circles. And you can get away with a construction that uses fewer lines.

There are lots of 19th century projective geometry texts on archive.org that explain this, but I'll point you to Hatton's [Projective Geometry, pg 132](https://archive.org/details/cu31924060184045/page/n147/mode/1up).

This illustration from that page shows the construction.

[image: Hatton Polar]

This construction gets away without computing $F$ because $Q$ is also on the polar.  The proof for this construction is give in the two preceding pages of the reference, and actually starts from the construction you give (chords $AA',BB',CC'$).

Answer (score 0):

EDIT1:

Harmonic mean $HM$ segments are of length
$$ (OA_1, OA_2) = OH_A,\, (OB_1, OB_2) = OH_B,\,(OC_1, OC_2)= OH_C,..$$ measured from the pole $O$ always lie on the polar line represented by red circle locus. It  contains points $ (H_A, H_B, H_C..) $ and end tangent points $ T_1 T_2 $ where the power of the circle is $ OT_1^2=OT_2^2$.

[image: Pole & Polar]

It is interesting that the neighboring segments can be used as well for this purpose as the points of intersection (black circles) continue to be on the polar, a fact interestingly relevant to draw chord line as tangent points $ T_1 T_2 $ connecting line.

Comment: It is continuation of an earlier answer (where I have mentioned about harmonic mean) can now be found another way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an excerpt from *Kiselev's Geometry; Book I: Planimetry (English Adaptation)* regarding tangents through a point:

> **Problem.** *Through a given point, to draw a tangent to a given circle.*
>
> Consider two cases:
>
> (1) *The given point* ($C$) *lies on the circle itself.* Then draw the radius to this point, and at its endpoint $C$, erect the perpendicular $AB$ to this radius [...].
>
> (2) *The given point* ($A$) *lies outside the disk bounded by the given circle.* Then, connecting $A$ with the center $O$, construct the circle with $AO$ as a diameter. Through the points $B$ and $B'$ at which this circle intersects the given one, draw the lines $AB$ and $AB'$. These lines are the required tangents, since the angles $OBA$ and $OB'A$ are right (as inscribed intercepting a diameter).

Note that the solution presented above does require a compass to draw a circle (i.e. the circle with diameter $AO$).

Here is an excerpt pertaining to the construction in `(1)` of the above excerpt:

> **Problem.** *To construct a right triangle given its hypotenuse $a$ and a leg $b$.*
>
> On a line $MN$, mark $AB = a$ and describe a semicircle with $AB$ as a diameter. (For this, bisect $AB$, and take the midpoint for the center of the semicircle and $\frac{1}{2}AB$ for the radius.) Then draw an arc of radius congruent to $b$ centered at point $A$ (or $B$). Connect the intersection point $C$ of the arc and the semicircle, with the endpoints of the diameter $AB$. The required triangle is $ABC$, since the angle $C$ is right, $a$ is the hypotenuse, and $b$ is a leg.

There is also another way of constructing right angles, which is more primitive that the excerpt above.

---

However, as mentioned already, these constructions require a compass in addition to a straightedge.

I'm not aware of a solution to your problem with solely a straightedge.

But, remember what a compass serves to do: find the locus of points equidistant from some point (i.e. draw a circle). Can we not do the same with a straightedge? Yes, and no. You can only find a finite amount with a straightedge, so it won't really be a locus. The compass merely draws *every* point with just a swipe of the wrist.

Let us "emulate" a compass with a straightedge:

### Answer

**Pick a point $A$ on your straightedge. Pick another point $B$ on your straightedge (such that $AB$ will be the radius of your desired circle). Put your pencil tip on this $B$ and start rotating the straightedge about $A$.**

My answer is more of a hack, rather than a geometric proof. If your life depended on finding a tangent to a circle going through some point, and you only had a straightedge, I recommend doing what I said above. However, don't torture yourself by not having a compass handy if you don't need to. `:)`

Comment: In (1), how do you get a perpendicular just with a straightedge ?

Comment: In (2), how do you find the midpoint of the circle with $AO$ as a diameter without a compass, and how do you find the points $B$ and $B'$ without drawing the new circle? I don't see how I could actually draw the construction without a compass.

Comment: @YvesDaoust : I'm not aware of such a possibility. However, see my updated answer and you can "emulate" a compass with a straightedge to construct `(1)` with just a straightedge.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta : I can't find a way **not** to use a compass. `:)`. However, as I mentioned to YvesDaoust, see my updated answer to see how you can "emulate" a compass with a straightedge. It's more of a hack than a true answer, I suppose. `:)`

Comment: One would assume that a compass is indeed necessary, but the method I put in my question does not use a compass and it seems to work. I just don't see why, and that was my question. Oh, and that is a hack. :o)

Answer (score -2):

The answer is because when you fix one line through $P$ that intersects the circle at $A_1$ and $A_2$ and vary a second line and hence its intersection points $B_1$ and $B_2$, the point $E$ defined by you varies on a line.

This should be fairly easy and boring to check with analytic geometry.

It bugs me too that I cannot see the reason in some ratios or some such though.

Comment: Have you actually checked that the calculation using analytic geometry is doable? Even if it is, it would be somewhat unsatisfactory, since there ought to be a proof "in a Euclidean spirit".

Comment: HINT
Harmonic mean of $ (OA_1, OA_2) $ ,.., .. always lies on (locus) $ FG $.